# ElasticSearch: Nested buckets aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new to ElasticSearch, so this question could be quite trivial for you, but here I go:

I'm using **kibana_sample_data_ecommerce**, which documents have a mapping like this

```
{
    ...
    "order_date" : <datetime>
    "taxful_total_price" : <double>
    ...
}
```

I want to get a basic daily behavior of the data:

[image: Sales a day behavior]

Expecting documents like this:

```
[
  {
    "qtime" : "00:00",
    "mean" : 20,
    "std" : 40
  },
  {
    "qtime" : "01:00",
    "mean" : 150,
    "std" : 64
  }, 
  ...
]
```

So, the process I think that I need to do is:

```
Group by day all records -> 
  Group by time window for each day -> 
    Sum all record in each time window -> 
      Cumulative Sum for each sum by time window, thus, I get behavior of a day ->
        Extended_stats by the same time window across all days
```

And that can be expressed like this:

[image: Nested bucket aggregation]

But I can't unwrap those buckets to process those statistics. May you give me some advice to do that operation and get that result?

Here is my current query(kibana developer tools):

```
POST kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "order_date": {
              "gt": "now-1M",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "day_histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "order_date",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "qmin_histo": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "order_date",
            "calendar_interval": "hour"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "qminute_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "taxful_total_price"
              }
            },
            "cumulative_qminute_sum": {
              "cumulative_sum": {
                "buckets_path": "qminute_sum"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot solve this problem at search time. You should consider splitting your resolution process in multiple queries while storing the partial results along the way. You should consider using a client for this. E.g., (1) group by day and time to calculate cumulative sum per day and time - i.e., what you posted - and store the results somewhere; (2) group by day and calculate extended statistics on the cumulative sums.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you pull off the extended stats:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "order_date": {
              "gt": "now-4M",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "order_date",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_hour": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "order_date",
            "calendar_interval": "hour"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_taxful_total_price": {
              "extended_stats": {
                "field": "taxful_total_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

[image]

Comment: But that `extended_stats` give me the `avg` and `std` for that bucket, i.e. `avg` and `std` for all the `taxful_total_price` that happen between `2020-07-02 00:00` and `2020-07-02 01:00`. The metric that I want to know is the `avg` and `std` in a time range e.g. `00:00-01:00`, for all the dates that I have (in your case `"gt": "now-4M"`)

Comment: So you need an hourly avg/std irregardless of the day? 1 bucket per 1 hour range --> 24 buckets in total?

Comment: Exactly!, but before I need to do the `cummulative_sum` in order to determine the behavior of each day